# Can a program respond to events in another application

Tags: c#, windows, events

I am tasked with writing a Windows application in C# that will connect and transfer data to an API.  I want this to occur whenever the user performs a certain action in a separate application.

The user has a piece of software that displays a table in an SQL database containing recently received order data.  The user can select any number of rows of orders, indicate that the orders have been shipped, and the program automatically puts the respective information in another SQL table containing data on shipped orders.  At this point, whatever data was moved can optionally be saved into a file of any format. Whenever the user performs this action, I want the C# program to capture the data on shipped orders, and do its thing.

Is this a fundamentally flawed idea, and if so what would be my best alternative to get the kind of behavior I'm looking for?

Comment: I get a notification that says "vote-up requires 15 reputation". I'd love to support this valuable community and point out the most helpful among us.

Comment: I keep forgeting that! Apologies. :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You haven't provided a great deal of details, but [`SqlDependency`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldependency.aspx) would fit your given requirements.

- [Using SqlDependency in a Windows Application](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a52dhwx7%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)
- [SqlDependency in an ASP.NET Application](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9dz445ks.aspx)